# Heroku Redis Add-On Error error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number

Tags: node.js, heroku, heroku-redis

After upgrading my Heroku Redis add-on to v6.2.3 from v4, Heroku papertrail logs display this error: `Error accepting a client connection: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number`  
 I am connecting to Redis using NodeJs and the `bull` npm package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/bull). I found similar questions related to this error, along with Heroku documentation, and based on that I have set my `bull` redis options to the following:

```
redis: {
    host: redisURL.hostname,
    port: Number(redisURL.port),
    password: redisURL.password,
    tls: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
    },
  },
```

Note the `tls` parameter. I have set it to Heroku's recommendations here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-redis#connecting-in-node-js 
 
 After getting stuck for a while, I attempted to simply comment out any client code that connects to Redis, delete the add-on, and re-provision the add-on. I expected to see no redis logs in papertrail when I did this, but I still see the same error, even when no code that connects to redis is being run... This leads me to believe maybe it's a setting on the actual Redis add-on instance, rather than an issue with my code, but I am at a loss.

**Updates:**

I logged into the redis:cli and did some investigation. `client list` reveals 2 client connections. 1 is the instance of the redis:cli I am running in my terminal, and another is the a client with a flag that means "the client is a replica node connection to this instance" (see https://redis.io/commands/client-list). What is interesting is the error that is being logged in papertrail shows the file descriptor for the client connection that is having the SSL error `fd=12`, while the 2 clients shown in `client list` have the file descriptors `fd=10` and `fd=11`. So there must be another client connection with `fd=12` that isn't appearing in `client list` command causing the error shown above.

Comment: I have the exact same issue and could not find a solution yet.

Comment: @funkenstrahlen I was able to log into the redis cli (to do this you run the command `heroku redis:cli -a <app_name>` What I found is interesting. Even after commenting out the client code in my app, there is always 1 client connection to the redis instance. Even after running `client kill` on the persistent client, it simply reconnects a new one and continues to display the error in papertrail. Sorry, I know that's not a solution but hopefully with that added context we can figure it out. I would like to know where this initial client connection is coming from, it may hold the answer.

Comment: I am having the same problem using `ioredis`.

Comment: I am facing the same issue after upgrading my Heroku Redis plan to 6.2.3.

Answer (score 4):

[Jasper Kennis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70864363/6590970) is correct. Adding `tls: {rejectUnauthorized: false}` fixed this issue for me. Unfortunately, Heroku only gives you a full `REDIS_URL` connection string, so you need to parse the password/host/port yourself (you can't specify both a URL and tls settings). Here's my `BullModule.forRoot()` config object if it helps:

```
redis: {
    password: process.env.REDIS_URL.split('@')[0].split(':')[2],
    host: process.env.REDIS_URL.split('@')[1].split(':')[0],
    port: parseInt(process.env.REDIS_URL.split('@')[1].split(':')[1]),
    tls: { rejectUnauthorized: false },
  }
```

Using:
@nestjs/bull: 0.6.0,
Heroku redis: 6.2.3

Comment: I am using the same versions of modules, and followed this answer.
It is working on local environment, but after deploying the app to Heroku I am getting the same error.

Comment: You could also parse the url string like this: `const redisUrl = new URL(REDIS_URL);`

Answer (score 2):

Ran into the same problem. In addition to `rejectUnauthorized: false`, adding `requestCert: true,` solved it for me. In addition, some clients need `agent: false,` (but the version of Bull I'm using doesn't recognise that argument)

```
  redis: {
    host: redisURL.hostname,
    port: Number(redisURL.port),
    password: redisURL.password,
    tls: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
      requestCert: true,
      // agent: false, (not all clients accept this)
    },
  },
```