# Why is @nestjs/bull not able to connect to Heroku Redis?

Tags: heroku, redis, nestjs, bull

This works for local `redis-server`

```
BullModule.forRoot({
    redis: {
        host: "localhost",
        port: 6379,
        db: 0,
        password: ""
    }
})
```

But if I use the DataStore Credentials on Heroku Redis, the bull board does not load and Heroku Logs gives an H12 error.

[image]

How can I get the `BullModule` to properly connect to Heroku Data for Redis?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You must specify the location of where redis is accessible. `localhost:6379` is the default for running redis locally, but to deploy an application that uses Redis to Heroku, you will need to add the [Connecting to Heroku Data for Redis](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-heroku-redis#connecting-in-node-js) add-on. Then, you'll need to pass the location of your Redis service via `process.env.REDIS_URL` to the `BullModule.forRoot()` constructor.

Be aware that encountering TLS issues in connecting to Redis like this are common. When I tried connecting using the format from [PedroPovedaQ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73524300/6590970), I ran into one.
There's a discusson on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69904099/heroku-redis-add-on-error-error1408f10bssl-routinesssl3-get-recordwrong-vers).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying

```
BullModule.forRoot({
    redis: "<redisurl given by heroku in env variable>"
})
```

This fixed the issue for me.